# Why don't touch-action: none work when descendant has scrollbar in chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

As we know that on Chrome browsers for touch devices the `ontouchmove` event cannot be prevented with `preventDefault()`. It requires the css property `touch-action: none` too. I tried applying this on `body` and it worked ok. But when I have an inner element that can be scrolled then when we keep scrolling down that element and when it's scrolling finishes further touchmove events start scrolling the `body`. Is this a bug in Chrome? I have made the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qe74qob/4/) for test. An inline example:

```js
window.ontouchmove = function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
body {
  touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  keep sccrolling down and this will also scroll body element.
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
  content
  <br>
</div>
Try scrolling here; it won't scroll!!
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
another content
```

When we try for example in Android Chrome browser then if we try to scroll in non-orange portion then it won't scroll -- good. But when we keep scrolling the orange portion down, and reach its end then the body starts scrolling. This shouldn't happen because body has `touch-action: none;`

Comment: As a quick check you could open chrome responsive dev tools and set a touch device and then scroll by touch moving through the orange portion.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list is where bugs in Chrome are logged.